# Adding images to JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, imageicon

I want to add images to my JButtons. I have tried to add the rollover icon command to one of my buttons, but I keep getting an exception even though eclipse doesn't say that there are any errors. I have saved the images in workspace/projectname/src where the class files are, and they are called a and b, and they are JPEG images.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

    public class button extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton hi;
    private JButton custom;

    public button() {
        super("The title");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        hi = new JButton("Hi button");

        Icon a = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("a.JPEG"));
        Icon b = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("b.JPEG"));
        custom = new JButton("custom", a);
        custom.setRolloverIcon(b);
        add(custom);
        add(hi);

        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        hi.addActionListener(handler);
        custom.addActionListener(handler);

    }
    private class HandlerClass implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("%s", event.getActionCommand()));
        }
    }
}

import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class buttonm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        button hello = new button();
        hello.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        hello.setSize(350,100);
        hello.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a guessing game.. "Guess what my exception is"?

Comment: I have to agree with @peeskillet. If you can give us more information with which to help you, perhaps then we can help you. Please read the [help] and [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections on what information we need.

Comment: _"but I keep getting an exception even though eclipse doesn't say that there are any errors"_ - You may also want to do some research on exceptions vs. compile errors. Generally they have nothing to do with each other (unless you are getting an uncompilable source exception)

Comment: If I have to _guess_ though, I'd guess a NullPointerException from invalid path. If your images are directly at the root of the src and your class is in some package below it, You want to put a `/` in the front of your path. If your image is in the same package as the java file, then your path is correct, and you really _should_ post your exception (stacktrace) for further help

Comment: 1) Always copy/paste error or exception output. 2) See also [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Answer (score 0):

the Button class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Button extends JFrame {

    private JButton button;
    private JPanel p;

    public Button() {
        super("The title");
        p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        button = new JButton();

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("button2.jpg"));
        button.setIcon(icon);
        button.setDisabledIcon(icon);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        p.add(button);
        add(p);

    }
}
```

your main class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setVisible(true);
    }
```